# Loading code from External Flash to RAM

Tags: arm

I am using an ARM Cortex M3 architecture, i am facing a problem with data corruption with my current code when my board is kept on, for a continuous period, as i am using the internal flash and ram and this may have caused some data rewritten in the data section. Now what i plan to use is an external flash that will have the program, the internal flash will have all the necessary initialization, once the board is booted the internal flash program is executed, then i want the code from the external flash be loaded in the ram and continue the flow. Please help with my approach or suggest me a better way.

Comment: have you upped the main clock without modifying the wait states for the flash?  when you power cycle is it corrupt then or does it work then appear corrupt later?  what do you see when you dump the flash, does it not match what you think you programmed?

Comment: ahh .data that is ram, generally runs as fast as the processor but maybe not depends on the design, maybe you are overclocking the ram?   sounds like it is just a simple bug in the code though.  running for a long time could just increase the odds of a glitch due to being on the edge of timing somewhere, allows events/interrupts in you werent planning for or maybe the ones you are planning for came too close or glitched and your code corrupts, etc...

Comment: My freq is 50Mhz, my board is designed to receive data from the server and display it through a 7seg display, at the start I set the IP of the board but after a period(7 days & more), when i check the IP it gets changed. But my board still receives the data and displays it. I am stuck at  this point.

Comment: is there a flash or ram wait state setting that when you up the clock to 50Mhz you have to increase the wait states?

Comment: are you driving the display directly from the microcontroller or are there transistors in there to boost power?  are you sure the microcontroller can drive those segments, esp worst case when they go all on?  It doesnt deplete the chip such that it is marginal on keeping the ram or other logic correct?   Likewise ground bounce when you go from all on to all off for however many signals you are driving at once?  how many of these have you built and how many have this problem?  have you run it for a long time with no display hooked up to eliminate that load and see if it still corrupts?

Comment: Thank You so much for ur Replies.....

Comment: The code was buggy as u said before....i sat with it an wrote most of it all again...

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be possible to write to the internal flash without going through a number of steps specific to the microcontroller, such as unlocking flash, providing addresses to erase, addresses to write, and an instruction to go. I would be surprised if this was happening randomly.

Do you do any flash writes? Check the code around these to see if that is the issue.

Are you sure that this is what's happening to you?

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use the internal flash and ram as designed.  There should be no reason for this external flash.  Sounds like buggy code, what have you done to prove it isnt?

If you wish to use one sure, go ahead, get a spi based flash or whatever device you want, the internal flash boots, copies the program from external to ram and runs it.

Why not just copy from internal flash to ram and run in ram?  If you trust the internal flash to boot from and init from then you should trust it to copy from.